# rails 3 mailer_action

Tags: ruby-on-rails, actionmailer, mailer

Any idea how can I send my model params to mail?

Here is the problem: I have a cardealler application and in car.show page I made a link called "Send email request"

```
<%= link_to 'Send email request',  send_to_mail_car_path(@car) %>
```

in cars_controller:

```
def send_to_mail
    CarMailer.request_email(@car).deliver
    @car = Car.find(params[:id])
    @search = Car.search(params[:search])
    redirect_to @car, :notice  => "Notification sent."
  end
```

that is working, I recieve mails from clients(that would be me, cause tha app it's in development stage).. but I recieve this mail as long it's only plain text in those 2 files:

`request_email.html.erb` and `request_email.text.erb`

when I am trying to add some car data it gives me errors.. so if I'll write in these files:

`<%= @car.id %>`  so I can view the id of car in mail, instead of id I have this error on my screen:

```
Called id for nil, which would mistakenly be 4 -- if you really wanted the id of nil, use object_id

4:     <meta content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" http-equiv="Content-Type" />
5:   </head>
6:   <body>
7:     <h1> <%= @car.id %></h1>
8:     <p>
```

in the user.confirm_registration tutorial is used also like this <%= user.name %> and I managed to get the user name in mail.. Why I can't see my car in my app then?

Any help will be apreciated. Some tutorials may be.. thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is here:

```
CarMailer.request_email(@car).deliver
@car = Car.find(params[:id])
```

You have to assign to `@car` before you can use it.

```
@car = Car.find(params[:id])
CarMailer.request_email(@car).deliver
```

Comment: Can I ask you one more things about sending pictures to mail? pictures=assets  assets belongs_to car  will it work like this?:

`<% for asset in @car.assets %>
    <%= image_tag(asset.asset.url(:original)) %>
  <% end %>`

Comment: Looks fine. In Ruby, we typically use `@car.assets.each do |asset|` rather than `for asset in @car.assets`, though.